# get printer in Active directory restricted or not

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I create a C# application that communicate with AD and I want to get if the printer is resticted or not from properties and its a piece of code here

```
deSearch.Filter = String.Format("(&&&(objectClass=printQueue)(printerName={0})(location={1})(driverName={2})))", queueName,location,modelNumber);
            SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
 foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
string Description = result.Properties["description"][0].ToString().Trim();
//how I can get here if this printer is restricted or not

}
```

I also found nTSecurityDescriptor attribute in printer attributes .Is it helpful for me or is can get if printer restricted or not?

**Note**  Its under .Net Framework 3.5

All ideas are welcomed

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean under "the printer is restricted"?

Comment: @Oleg: unrestricted means allow user to print and restricted means deny to print

Comment: In the case the exact users token must be checked against the security descriptor of the printer. See `AccessCheck` function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374815(VS.85).aspx). See example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379648(VS.85).aspx. You can also use other API like `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637(VS.85).aspx). Is it what you need?

Comment: @Oleg : I am not familiar with C++ .Are you have tutorial for that by C#?

Comment: Look at the example of usage `AccessCheck` API in C# here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/accessctrl3.aspx#Accesscheck (see `DoRegistryAccessCheck` example). I hope you can easy modify the example to use instead of `byte [] RawForm = regKey.GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm()` the security descriptor of the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/qPrintComponent.aspx) there's a sample that uses it.

Comment: your link didn't get printers from Active Directory